# Highchart stacked bar chart pagination

Tags: highcharts

I need to show the stacked bar chart with pagination 
i need Pagination structure/options like this :-

```
[First Previous 12 13 14 15 Next Last]
```

1st page need to show only this values

```
'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'
```

2nd page need to show only this values

```
'Apples1', 'Oranges1', 'Pears1', 'Grapes1', 'Bananas1'
```

3rd page need to show only this values

```
'Apples2', 'Oranges2', 'Pears2', 'Grapes2', 'Bananas2'
```

based on the `xAxis - Categories` values count I want to show pagination

Have a sample code in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/38L9nhhs/2/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas','Apples1', 'Oranges1', 'Pears1', 'Grapes1', 'Bananas1','Apples2', 'Oranges2', 'Pears2', 'Grapes2', 'Bananas2']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2,3, 4, 4, 2, 5,2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1,5, 3, 4, 7, 2,3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5,2, 2, 3, 2, 1,5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }]
   });
  });
```

Please help me any one to achive this

Comment: How about using `xAxis.max` and `xAxis.min`? You can change extremes using `xAxis.setExtremes()`. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/38L9nhhs/8/ Now just generate buttons according to the logic behind your pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need to do is:

1. Create an additional array holding the base elements (oranges, apples, pears, etc.)
2. Build a pager on page launch based on the number of base elements and elements contained in the arrCategories array
3. Load the graph for page 0 which would be the default page without the numbers appended

Here are the relevant code parts:

**HTML**

```
<!-- add a pager below the graph -->
<div id="page-container">Page: <span id="pager"></span></div>
```

**JS**

```
// create the arrays outside of the function scope, otherwise accessing elements later-on
// may cause problems
var arrBaseCategories = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'];
// arrCategories and arrSeries "data" element must contain the number of arrBaseCategories n-times
var arrCategories = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Apples1', 'Oranges1', 'Pears1', 'Grapes1', 'Bananas1', 'Apples2', 'Oranges2', 'Pears2', 'Grapes2', 'Bananas2'];
var arrSeries = [{
  name: 'John',
  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}];

function showGraph(page) {

  // number of different elements
  var numDifferentElements = arrBaseCategories.length;
  // first element that needs to be extracted from arrCategories and arrSeries
  var intStartElement = page * numDifferentElements;

  var arrCurrentSeries = [];
  var arrCurrentCategories = [];

  // loop all series for all persons, extract part of the data array for the given page
  for (var elem in arrSeries) {

    var arrSubData = [];

    // extract elements starting from a position based on the page number 
    // from the data array and only pass this one along when creating the chart
    for (var i = 0; i < numDifferentElements; i++) {

      arrCurrentCategories.push(arrCategories[intStartElement + i]);
      arrSubData.push(arrSeries[elem].data[intStartElement + i]);

    }
    arrCurrentSeries.push({
      name: arrSeries[elem].name,
      data: arrSubData
    });

  }

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: arrCurrentCategories
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: arrCurrentSeries
  });
} // end function showGraph

$(function() {

  // create a pager on start
  function initialisePager() {
    var numPages = Math.ceil(arrCategories.length / arrBaseCategories.length);

    for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
      var link = '<a href="javascript:showGraph(' + i + ')">' + Math.round(i + 1) + '</a>';
      $('#pager').append(link);
    }
  }

  initialisePager();
  showGraph(0);
});
```

The complete fiddle with more than one person inside the series can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/38L9nhhs/7/